# Multiple Panels - How can i link a button from a class to another class?

Tags: java, swing

I have 4 classes to be exactly. But more importantly, the class which show first it's called "MultiplePanels" . 
This class(MultiplePanels) has 2 buttons, the first one "Memoreaza" is linked to class Frame. It's working fine. (If it is needed, i can give that one class, too).
The second class "FileWriterUsingJFrame" it's also linked as the previous one. But everytime i try to do something appear any kind of errors.

What i do wrong? I've tried lots of toturials from YT & from here. 
And sorry , i'm new in terms of java-swing . 
//Also, i've tried to remove the  "throw new...." comments from class "FileWriterUsingJFrame" as i saw that may be the problem. But it isn't ...

Thanks alot!

This is the MultiplePanels Class

```
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiplePanels extends JFrame {

public MultiplePanels() {
 GridLayout g1=new GridLayout();

    g1.setRows(1);
    setLayout(g1);

    setTitle("My Gui");
    setSize(600, 200);




    JButton button = new JButton("Memoreaza");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Inregistreaza");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();



    panel.add(button);
     panel.add(button2);



   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            try {
                Frame frame=new Frame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MultiplePanels.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });

   button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea)
        {
            FileWriterUsingJFrame frame1=new FileWriterUsingJFrame();
            frame1.setVisible(true);

        }
    });


    add(button);
    add(button2);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

This is  my "FileWriterUsingJFrame" class.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FileWriterUsingJFrame implements ActionListener{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Hotel Ibis");
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();


    private static String[] message = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(message); 

        JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField();
         JTextField passwordTextField = new JTextField();
         JTextField password2TextField = new JTextField();
         JTextField password3TextField = new JTextField();
         JTextField password4TextField = new JTextField();
         JTextField password5TextField = new JTextField();
JTextField password6TextField = new JTextField();





         JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel ("Nume");
         JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel ("CI || Serie");        
         JLabel password2Label = new JLabel ("Prenume");
         JLabel password3Label = new JLabel ("Nr Persoane");
         JLabel password4Label = new JLabel ("Data sosire");
         JLabel password5Label = new JLabel ("Data plecare");
         JLabel password6Label = new JLabel ("Nr camere inchiriate");

         JButton signUpButton = new JButton("Inregistreaza");
         JButton generate = new JButton ("factura");


JLabel blank=new JLabel();
FileWriter fileWriter;

   FileWriterUsingJFrame(){

        GridLayout g1=new GridLayout();
        g1.setColumns(3);
        g1.setRows(10);

        window.setLayout(g1);


        signUpButton.addActionListener(this);
         generate.addActionListener(this);

window.add(userNameLabel);
window.add(userNameTextField);

window.add(passwordLabel);
window.add(passwordTextField);

window.add(password2Label);
window.add(password2TextField);

window.add(password3Label);
window.add(password3TextField);

window.add(password4Label);
window.add(password4TextField);

window.add(password5Label);
window.add(password5TextField);

window.add(password6Label);
window.add(password6TextField);
window.add(blank);
window.add(box);

window.add(blank);
window.add(signUpButton);




window.add(generate);
box.setSelectedIndex(0);
box.addActionListener(box);




                window.setSize(400,300);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setVisible(true);


    }



    FileWriterUsingJFrame(JButton b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea) {


if(ea.getActionCommand() == signUpButton.getActionCommand())
    {

        try
        {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter("D:/kek.txt", true);

            fileWriter.write(userNameLabel.getText() +  " : " +userNameTextField.getText()+ " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(passwordLabel.getText() + " : " +passwordTextField.getText() + " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(password2Label.getText() + " : " +password2TextField.getText()+ " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(password3Label.getText() + " : " +password3TextField.getText() + " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(password4Label.getText() + " : " +password4TextField.getText() + " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(password5Label.getText() + " : " +password5TextField.getText() + " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(password6Label.getText() + " : " +password6TextField.getText() + " " + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            fileWriter.write(  " etajul" + "" + "" + box.getSelectedItem() + "" + " " + " " + " ");
            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            fileWriter.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            fileWriter.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Informatii trecute cu succes!");

        }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e+"");}
} 
}

private void password6TextFieldPressed(final java.awt.event.KeyEvent event) 
 {
int key = event.getKeyCode();
if ((key >= event.VK_0 && key <= event.VK_9)
        || (key >= event.VK_NUMPAD0 && key <= event.VK_NUMPAD9)
        || key == event.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
    this.password6TextField.setEditable(true);
    this.password6TextField.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
} else {
    this.password6TextField.setEditable(false);
    this.password6TextField.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
  } 

    void setVisible(boolean b) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{ {
FileWriterUsingJFrame fwj = new FileWriterUsingJFrame();
}}
    }
```

Comment: Wonder if you code is even compile. Have `frame1.setVisible(true);` but `FileWriterUsingJFrame` is a `(J)Frame` ?

Comment: @TraianGEICU Yes it is a JFrame. And yes, try to compile firstly.

Comment: This is what you believe to be, but is not. Just a regular class that implement an interface. see `extends` what is doing.  Regarding compiling for sure it wont but now have no idea what you really compile.

Comment: More over see what is the usage of `public static void main(String[] args)`  in `FileWriterUsingJFrame`

Comment: Alright. Do you have any idea what should i try ?

Comment: Fine, I can show you some hints but not doing all coding for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Hints, not an answer.

setVisible() is Method form JFrame here, so work only if you have an obj. of type JFrame
(method is inherited in JFrame from [Window](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)). That's why not compiling)

How to extends an object ? and other adjustments

```
public class FileWriterUsingJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //now your class is a JFrame having all methods from including  setVisible()
    //as you did on Multiplepannel

    //remove line 
    //JFrame window = new JFrame("Hotel Ibis");

    //add line in constructor `FileWriterUsingJFrame()`
    setTitle("Hotel Ibis");

    //use (this) instead of (window) : (this) is the current object 
    //since you wanted  FileWriterUsingJFrame to be display and not a nested class from

    //window.add(userNameLabel); should be
    this.add(userNameLabel);
    // work also even without this, since you refer your current obj
    //add(userNameLabel);
}
```

Remove `public static void main(String[] args)` since you create the frame form `Multipannel` on button2 click

Those should fix your code to compile and display the frame on click

(if `FileWriterUsingJFrame` is doing what is suppose to do that is another story)


Hope my hints could help you to correct your code.

Comment: I've tried now with your hints and yes, it worked. Wow, it was actually really easy. I've tried as you said " public class FileWriterUsingJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener" then i removed the "JFrame window = new JFrame("Hotel Ibis");" and then i just removed " this .add"  .

Comment: Hope you replace all window with [this or nothing] ... eg: window.add goes into this.add or just add. Glad that i could help you